# Web scrape table from site

Tags: python, r, web-scraping, python-requests, httr

I want to web scrape one table from following website: https://www.katastar.hr

To follow what I want, please open inspect, than click network.
Now, when you open site you can see there is a URL:
https://oss.uredjenazemlja.hr/rest/katHr/lrInstitutions/position?id=2432593&status=1332094865186&x=undefined&y=undefined

The problem is that id and status are different every time you open the site.
How can I **scrape** output of the above request (which is a json, that is a table), when there is different GET queries every time?

I would give reproducible example, but there is nothing special I can try. I should start from home page, but I don't know how to proceed:

```
headers <- c(
  "Accept" = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
  'Accept-Encoding' = "gzip, deflate, br",
  'Accept-Language' = 'hr-HR,hr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
  "Cache-Control" = "max-age=0",
  "Connection" = "keep-alive",
  "DNT" = "1",
  "Host" = "www.katastar.hr",
  "If-Modified-Since" = "Mon, 22 Mar 2021 13:39:38 GMT",
  "Referer" = "https://www.google.com/",
  "sec-ch-ua" = '"Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
  "sec-ch-ua-mobile" = "?0",
  "Sec-Fetch-Dest" = "document",
  "Sec-Fetch-Mode" = "navigate",
  "Sec-Fetch-Site" = "same-origin",
  "Sec-Fetch-User" = "?1",
  "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" = "1",
  "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36"
)
p <- httr::GET(
  "https://www.katastar.hr/",
  add_headers(headers))
httr::cookies(p)
```

The code can be in both R and python.

Comment: There is enough info to understand the problem. I suspect they are generated but 1 or 2 of the source js scripts.

Comment: Hi @Qharr, is it possible to somehow execute JavaScript and get status and id? I suppose this is done on server side automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need the http header `Origin` to make it work:

- python

```py
import requests

r = requests.get(
    "https://oss.uredjenazemlja.hr/rest/katHr/lrInstitutions/position?id=2432593&status=1332094865186&x=undefined&y=undefined",
    headers={
        "Origin": "https://www.katastar.hr"
    })

print(r.json())
```

repl.it: https://replit.com/@bertrandmartel/ScrapeKatastar

- R

```
library(httr)

data <- content(GET(
  "https://oss.uredjenazemlja.hr/rest/katHr/lrInstitutions/position?id=2432593&status=1332094865186&x=undefined&y=undefined",
  add_headers(origin = "https://www.katastar.hr")
  ), as = "parsed", type = "application/json")

print(data)
```

---

To go a little further into how the website generates `id` and `status`, there is this following code in JS:

```js
e.prototype.getSurveyors = function(e) {
    var t = this.runbase(),
      n = this.create(t.toString(), null);
    return this.httpClient.get(s + "/position", {
      params: {
        id: t.toString(),
        status: n,
        x: String(e[0]),
        y: String(e[1])
      }
    })
}
e.prototype.runbase = function() {
    return Math.floor(1e7 * Math.random())
}
e.prototype.create = function(e, t) {
    for (var n = 0, i = 0; i < e.length; i++) n = (n << 5) - n + e.charAt(i).charCodeAt(0), n &= n;
    return null == t && (t = e), Math.abs(n).toString().substring(0, 6) + (Number(t) << 1)
}
```

It takes a random number `id` and encodes it using a specific algorithm, and puts the result into `status` field. The server then checks if `status` encoded value match the `id` value.

It seems previous `id` values still work as in the sample above (in case there is no data sent), but you can also reproduce the JS function above like this (example in [python](/questions/tagged/python)):

```py
from random import randint
import ctypes
import requests

number = randint(1000000, 9999999)

def encode(rand, data):
    randStr = str(rand)
    n = 0
    for char in randStr:
        n = ctypes.c_int(n << 5).value - n + ord(char)
    n = ctypes.c_int(n & n).value
    if data is None:
        suffix = ctypes.c_int(rand << 1).value
    else:
        suffix = ctypes.c_int(data << 1).value
    return f"{str(abs(n))[:6]}{suffix}"

r = requests.get("https://oss.uredjenazemlja.hr/rest/katHr/lrInstitutions/position",
                 params={
                     "id": number,
                     "status": encode(number, None)
                 },
                 headers={
                     "Origin": "https://www.katastar.hr"
                 })
print(r.json())

# GET parcel Id 13241901
parcelId = 13241901
r = requests.get("https://oss.uredjenazemlja.hr/rest/katHr/parcelInfo",
                 params={
                     "id": number,
                     "status": encode(number, parcelId)
                 },
                 headers={
                     "Origin": "https://www.katastar.hr"
                 })
print(r.json())
```

repl.it: https://replit.com/@bertrandmartel/ScrapeKatastarDecode

Comment: ```e.prototype.getCesticaInfo=function(e){
 var t=this.runbase(),
  n=this.create(t.toString(),e);
 return this.httpClient.get("https://oss.uredjenazemlja.hr/rest/katHr/parcelInfo",{
  params:{
   id:t.toString(),
   status:n
  }
 })
}

Comment: This is awsome! I have found another url I want to get data from, but I couldn't get right status code. I have found JS code which generates status from id, but it seems it can't be generated with your encode function. I know this is another question, but it would be very helpfull. `e.prototype.getCesticaInfo=function(e){
 var t=this.runbase(),
  n=this.create(t.toString(),e);
 return this.httpClient.get("https://oss.uredjenazemlja.hr/rest/katHr/parcelInfo",{
  params:{
   id:t.toString(),
   status:n
  }
 })
}`

Comment: This is generated by clicking "Pronađi katatarsku česticu" on the site, than choose 'Katastarska općina' and than 'Broj katastarske cestice'. This generates https://oss.uredjenazemlja.hr/rest/katHr/parcelInfo?id=1192092&status=19950126483802. I am just interest in calculating status from id.

Comment: @MislavSagovac yes in the answer above the argument was `null`, I will add the data argument to the `encode` function

Comment: @MislavSagovac please see updated post, I've also fixed the algorithm in the encode function